# Does anyone know of a software I can use to make a simple forest plot from RR and CI?

Tags: software

I'm trying to display a summary of the data from multiple trials for an infographic I have to produce.

Not all studies reported Mean +/- SD for their data so I can't populate an SPSS sheet etc. Revman has been discontinued. The online versions don't collate a pooled estimate and the one that does is awful and doesn't display the CIs.

Is there is simple way of developing a forest plot if I only have RR, CI and weight, not the raw data?

I saw an answer on here from 2013 but RevMan has now been discontinued.

It's not intended for publication.

Comment: Hi! You may be more likely to get an answer by asking your question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (it seems that there are more active users than here, and it is focused specifically on software recommendations)